# How to avoid PlaybackFailureException in coded UI during sending keyboard keys to Outlook Message Window?

Tags: outlook, coded-ui-tests

I'm trying to send keyboard sequence ctrl+c to message field in outlook's meeting form (ControlType=Client;Name=Message) and get the PlaybackFailureException.

The element was found successful and I can send an any text there, but not keyboard keys. There are two ways that I tried:

1) using modifiers:

```
elements_object.SetFocus();
Keyboard.SendKeys("{A}", ModifierKeys.Control);
Keyboard.SendKeys("{C}", ModifierKeys.Control);
```

This way just type A and then C to the field. Action that I expect wasn't executed (selecting + copying)

2) without modifiers:

```
elements_object.SendKeys("{^a}");
elements_object.SendKeys("{^c}");
```

This way threw the exception PlaybackFailureException .

There is interesting thing: for example send of {ENTER} is work.

What am I doing wrong, guys ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to perform Ctrl+A, Use

```
Keyboard.SendKeys("^a");
```

To Perform Ctrl + C,

```
Keyboard.SendKeys("^c");
```

If you would like to pass control on which, sendkeys has to perform:

```
  Keyboard.SendKeys(UITestControl, "^c");
```

Check Here to know more about SendKeys:[MSDN SendKeys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitesting.keyboard.sendkeys.aspx)

**Edit**

I tried the below code (*May be quick & dirty*) and it works for me:

```
 WinWindow outlook = new WinWindow();
        outlook.SearchProperties.Add(WinWindow.PropertyNames.Name, "Untitled - Meeting  ");
        WinClient doc = new WinClient(outlook);
        doc.SearchProperties.Add(WinWindow.PropertyNames.Name, "Document1");
        WinClient msg = new WinClient(doc);
        msg.SearchProperties.Add(WinWindow.PropertyNames.Name, "Message");

        Keyboard.SendKeys(msg, "^a");
        Keyboard.SendKeys(msg, "^c");
// I tried pasting it, it pastes same content whatever is copied.
        Keyboard.SendKeys(msg, "^v");
```

Comment: I'm sorry. There is a little missunderstanding. I wasn't enough specific. In my case method SendKeys() which I call from object is just wrapper with logging and of course inside it I have common Keyboard.SendKeys("^c")

So after your reply I tried your options:
1)   `code`Keyboard.SendKeys("^a");
      Keyboard.SendKeys("^c");`code`
2)   `code`Keyboard.SendKeys(GetControl(), "^a");
      Keyboard.SendKeys(GetControl(), "^c");`code`

Comment: The both options didn't throw any exceptians but also didn't execute actions that I expected. It looks like nothing happen. I expect that ctrl+a selects all text in a control and then ctrcl+c copies this selected text. Maybe am I wrong here and it's impossible ?

Comment: Check out my answer, I have edited my post with code which worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it exactly works, but maybe it'll be useful for someone in future. The approach is click to this field and then all shortcuts are working fine. Without clicking it doesn't work.